# Set drawable for DividerItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set my custom drawable (line) for DividerItemDecoration, but with no success. Where is the mistake?

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sk_line_divider));
```

XML shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000">
    </stroke>
</shape>
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need `DividerItemDecoration#setDrawable`, you can set `android:listDivider` attribute in your theme instead.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Change the shape to rectangle.

Ex:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 12):

**Programmatic (Solution):**

If you just want to **change the color** for the dividers instead of creating a custom drawable you can use a ColorDrawable:

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
itemDecoration.setDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.greycc));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

If the **size** matters in addition to colors you can use a GradientDrawable:

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{0xfff7f7f7, 0xfff7f7f7});
drawable.setSize(1,1);
itemDecoration.setDrawable(drawable);

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

**Note** that setting the color values in the array requires a full octet of hex values, otherwise incorrect colors will be shown i.e., 0x**FF**3E3E3E as opposed to 0X3E3E3E.

**Colored Dividers Update (2023):**

```
val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
itemDecoration.setDrawable(
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, android.R.color.holo_green_light, theme)!!
)
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
```

Comment: Setting ColorDrawable doesn't work - results in no decoration drawn at all.

Comment: @RomanKotenko Please see my Colored Dividers Update

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change divider color, you can change it from you AppTheme by adding this line
`<item name="android:listDivider">@color/your_color</item>`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [arekolek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916449/arekolek), I didn't know there's an API like this for `android:listDivider`.

But, there's a few way you can customise the `DividerItemDecoration`.

You'll need a drawable for the customised separator.

`bg_border_grey.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/borderGrey" />
</shape>
```

**Method #1 - Theme**

If you want apply theme wide, you can just add an attribute. Then, it will propagate down the children with the same theme.

`styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:listDivider">@drawable/bg_border_grey</item>
</style>
```

**Method #2 - Programmatically**

If you want to just customise the `DividerItemDecoration` itself and directly. Just `setDrawable` and you'll be right as rain.

```kotlin
val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(
    binding.recyclerView.context,
    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
)
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_border_grey))
binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_decoration));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecorationVertical = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        dividerItemDecorationVertical.setDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_decoration));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecorationVertical);
```

Answer (score 0):

May it help to someone.

Based on @[Morgan-Koh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867351/morgan-koh), Created ShapeDrawable programmatically

```
    val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    //decoration.setDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE))
    val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable()
    shapeDrawable.paint.color = Color.WHITE
    shapeDrawable.intrinsicHeight = 2
    shapeDrawable.intrinsicWidth = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi
    decoration.setDrawable(shapeDrawable)
    recyclerView?.addItemDecoration(decoration)
```