# Unable to set Custom Drawable for DividerItemDecoration for RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` displaying items horizontally and I want to add spacing between each items(but not at the start or end). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528012/set-drawable-for-divideritemdecoration) and also looked at the example from the official docs and even though I have declared the variable using var I get the following error:

[image]

I have configured my recycler view as follows:

```
myRecyclerView.apply {
  layoutManager = myLayoutManager
  adapter = myAdapter(data)
  addItemDecoration(divider)
}
```

It compiles and runs when I remove the line where I set my custom drawable.
Why am I getting this error and how do you set a custom drawable?

Comment: Try [calling `setDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DividerItemDecoration#setDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) directly, rather than using the Kotlin property syntax. That Kotlin property syntax should work, as both `getDrawable()` and `setDrawable()` exist. But, either `setDrawable()` will work or its error will (hopefully) give you a better idea of what the real underlying problem is.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please explain why the Kotlin property syntax did not work here?

Comment: Off the cuff, I can't. The Kotlin property syntax relies on there being a matching getter and setter, for the same type. It appears that `DividerItemDecoration` has those. Either you are running into some sort of IDE bug, or there is some subtle difference here that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because in the `DividerItemDecoration`

```
public void setDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable) 
@Nullable public Drawable getDrawable()
```

It means that the setter method accepts a `Drawable` while the getter return a `Drawable?`. Since they don't match you have to use the setter directly:

```
divider.setDrawable(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by CommonsWare, it worked after changing `divider.drawable = drawableResource` to `divider.setDrawable(drawableResource)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension function below;

```
fun RecyclerView.setDecoration(@DrawableRes source: Int) {
val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(this.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, source)
    ?.let {
        itemDecoration.setDrawable(it)
        this.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
    }
```

}

Usage;

```
binding.rvFiles.setDecoration(R.drawable.separator_line)
```